# Retrieve variables from webpage

Tags: javascript, variables, cookies

I need to retrieve some variables from a website where you need to login. To work around the Same Origin Policy I have put a proxy.php on my server. This works to retrieve variables from sites where a login is not required...

However, how can I retrieve data from a website where you need to log in?

Is it possible to download the 'LogIn' cookie and put in on my server? 
Or is it possible to open this site manually, and then retrieve the variables in javascript by referring to the opened Browser screen?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't access a login window opened with window.open from the window opener if they are not the same origine same as frames, iframes and xhr.\

Comment: What you describe is *exactly* what the same origin policy is designed to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create cookie in javascript with some unique id and save its record in server side storage and during login you can match cookie detail of client to server side detail of cookie and do your stuff.

Comment: How would I need to name the cookie?

Comment: you can create cookie with its name you can use client system ip address to give its unique name

Answer (score 0):

Is this to be used by many users?

If so then how are the users supposed to trust you? They will send their user name and password to your server?

If you only use this for yourself you can use force cors plugin with firefox (after installing click view => toolbar => addon bar and click on the "cors" text at the right bottom). With that active you can xmlhttprequest to any site.

If you want the service to be available for users of your site but using only one account you can look into curl but it might not be thread save (multiple user using it at the same time). If this is the case than I suggest removing this question and re posting it as a PHP question. How to PHP proxy xhr request.

Comment: I'd go with forcecors plugin then. Saves you a lot of trouble to program the php proxy unless you're realy good at using curl (then you can create a php console app). With forcecors; after retreiving the info you can fill it in a form, set the action to your (local) webserver and post it.

Comment: You're the man! It works ;) I have one extra question though, what are the exact safety dangers of this plug-in exactly ?(i will turn off this add-on when I am not running my stock exchange script).

Comment: If someone were to inject malicious script in let's say your email it could send your log on cookie by xhr. But mostly malicous scripts would use something like <img src="mybadsite?yourcookie... Same origin is to protect sites from "leaching" website using their services without permission. If site A allows site B to use it's service through xhr requests then they will either expose JSONP or set cors response headers. You can turn of forcecors for normal browsing. Wikipedia has a good article on same origin policy and the ways around it.